# Linux Mint 20.2 DNS not resolving internal hosts

Tags: linux-mint, dns, dnsmasq, systemd-resolved

Clean install of Linux Mint Uma (20.2) yesterday. All is well except for local network DNS resolution.

I have dnsmasq running on a Pine64 primarily so that I can use Steven Black's block list. It has been working very well for years, including with the previous version of Mint (Ulyana) that Uma replaced. External hosts can be resolved just fine but internal hosts are not. Example

```
dig cnn.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> cnn.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64483
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;cnn.com.                       IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
cnn.com.                56      IN      A       151.101.1.67
cnn.com.                56      IN      A       151.101.65.67
cnn.com.                56      IN      A       151.101.129.67
cnn.com.                56      IN      A       151.101.193.67

;; Query time: 27 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Mon Jul 12 08:41:19 PDT 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 100
```

but

```
dig lorien

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> lorien
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 9643
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;lorien.                                IN      A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Mon Jul 12 08:42:16 PDT 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 35
```

Note that lorien is a server on my local network with an ip of 192.168.1.3.

My dns box is at 192.168.1.20 and querying that box directly returns lorien's IP as expected.

```
dig lorien @192.168.1.20

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> lorien @192.168.1.20
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64326
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;lorien.                                IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
lorien.                 0       IN      A       192.168.1.3

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.20#53(192.168.1.20)
;; WHEN: Mon Jul 12 08:44:09 PDT 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 51
```

It would seem that systemd-resolved is not forwarding the request. Does it know about my dns box?

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.20        
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.20        
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa    

(other addresses omitted)
```

Yes it does.

I have 3 Network Manager configurations created, one purely DHCP, one Address Only (getting DNS server info from dnsmasq on .20) and one entirely static. DNS resolution behavior is the same in each case.

Can someone tell me what the problem is and how to fix this?

Thanks